# Resize one textarea with another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, textarea

I have a website with a few pages, each containing two textareas. All I'm trying to do is get it so that when the user resizes one of the textboxes, the other one sizes with it.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**Attempt #1**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var taheight;
    $('textarea').resize(function(){
        taheight = $(this).height();
        $('textarea').not(this).css('height',taheight);
    });
});
```

I also tried `.on('resize', function()...` and some other variations before realising it couldn't be done that way on account of the fact the resize functionality on textareas is a browser control, rather than part of the DOM.

Then I found this jsFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/gbouthenot/D2bZd/](http://jsfiddle.net/gbouthenot/D2bZd/)

I tried modifying it and came up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var textareaResize = function(source, dest) {
        var resizeInt = null;
        var thisTextArea;

        var resizeEvent = function() {
            dest.outerHeight(source.outerHeight());
        };

        source.on("mousedown", function(e) {
            resizeInt = setInterval(resizeEvent, 1000/30);
            thisTextArea = $(this).attr('id');
        });

        $(window).on("mouseup", function(e) {
            if (resizeInt !== null) {
                clearInterval(resizeInt);
            }
            resizeEvent();
        });
    };

    textareaResize($("#" + thisTextArea), $("textarea"));

});
```

But that wouldn't get the id of the target textarea. I also tried `thisTextArea = e.target.id`, but that wouldn't work either.

Help! Where are am I going wrong?

Comment: *"But that wouldn't get the id of the target textarea."* Why do you need that. It seems that this code does what you stated you wanted.

Comment: the code needs an input and an output element (see the last line). Because I can't set the id manually (as per the original jsfiddle), I need it to get the id of the resized textarea and use that as the input.

Comment: Also, I need the script to work across both textareas, where as the example jsfiddle only has one resizable textarea

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using jQuery UI `resizable()` and call the resize event from it.

```
$("textarea").resizable({
  resize: function() {
    //To get the id of the textarea being resized
    var id = $(this).find('textarea').attr('id');
    //You could also just put the resize function code here
  }
});
```

[**jQuery UI Resizable**](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

Comment: That would work but it means having to use jQuery UI, which I'd rather avoid and go for a js/jQuery solution if possible. Thanks though